# Connecting an environmental sensor to multiple smart phones

Tags: sensor, bluetooth, android

Newbie heading for the deep end here, I am working on a project where a number of students will use smart phones to connect via bluetooth to sensors placed around a woodland.  It has occurred to me that with 20 or so phones looking for the correct bluetooth to connect too could be a bit confusing. I am hoping to enable the correct connection using QR smart tags.

My other problem is a bit more difficult....for me anyway....
Most blue tooth devices can handle 8 connections at once it seems, unfortunately the sensor device I am using can only connect with one mobile device at a time.
A suggestion has been made that it could be possible to use one android phone to blue tooth connect to the sensor then relay the information to other blue tooth connected phones...

[image: *Above there was to be a picture illustrating the proposed setup but I am too new to post pictures sadly...(picture paints a thousand words and all that)*]

....I believe I am talking about making the first phone a bluetooth hot spot???? This will run the APP for the sensor. Add in a smart tag to connect student phones to the first mobile.

This is just one option I am looking at and I could do with some help please.

Is it possible to re-transmit what is on the screen of the first mobile to up to seven student smart phones at a time? Or maybe re-transmit the incoming signal to the first phone and run the same app on all the others?

If this turns out to be a total non starter I do have a plan "B" but I would like to stick with this at the moment...... unless an expert out there has a plan"X" that does what I want without any major design work!

Comment: Link to your picture and someone will edit the question to inline it for you.

Comment: I'd use the 1st phone to upload the data to a web-page or server / e-mail where everyone can access it.

Comment: http://i68.photobucket.com/albums/i9/alaskafriendor2/bluetoothcon01_zps8cb8c59b.jpg

Comment: Sorry about the curt image link, I am not used to this forum....finger trouble :) Thanks for the offer to upload it for me.   I am afraid that loading to a web page is not an option as this is in woodland with no wifi or other access....  In fact phone signals are nonexistant in most places.

Comment: I will bring the answer back here when I get. Thanks for editing my first post whoever did that for me :)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use one mobile phone as the bluetooth "base", which connects to the sensor modules. This cellphone would also run a web server, such as [kWS - Android Web Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xeustechnologies.android.kws&hl=en), and would be configured as a WiFi hotspot.

The other cellphones would then connect to this hotspot, and access the web server.

You would need to modify your existing sensor data retrieval application to provide the data suitably formatted to the web server as content.

Comment: Yes! I can see how that would work, I can discuss the output from the sensor in the correct format with the manufacturer.

Comment: I will bring the answers back here when I get them.